# How to resolve an error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios, podfile-lock

When I add new plugin in Flutter, I get this error in my runner xcode:

> The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation

and I have already install CocoaPods and updated. I tried to run pod install and not fixed it help please

Answer (score 43):

In my case the issue was caused by a local android only plugin. I created a dummy podsec file for the plugin, then ran:

```
cd ios
flutter pub get
pod install
pod update
```

It seems like I need to do these steps after every xcode project clean now.

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-AU)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
```

Comment: @MebroukiAmine Do you get any errors from pod install? Try removing pods folder first.

Comment: just running cd ios
flutter pub get
pod install
pod update fixed it for me

Answer (score 28):

In my case, i have cleaned the build and then updated the pod files , yet there were some warnings but those can be neglected:

```
> flutter clean
> flutter pub get
> cd ios
> pod update
```

Comment: This worked for me but with a slight change

> flutter clean
> flutter pub get
> cd ios
> rm Podfile.lock
> pod install

**Note : On mac this did not work from terminal in android studio but worked in the Terminal app **

Answer (score 8):

If anyone on an M1 Mac runs into this and gets an error running `pod update`, for me the fix was not running that command from VS Code but in the default terminal after setting it to `Open using Rosetta`.

[image]

After that it updated properly and I could build my app.

Answer (score 1):

Open the iOS folder in finder

- Delete Podlock file
- Delete pods folder

Then open terminal in iOS folder

- run  pod install

then open Runner.xcworkspace and run the app it will work

Answer (score 0):

In my case the message appeared because I did not have the Podfile nor the Podfile.lock. Strangely by running `flutter pub get` it did not generated them either. Then I decided to add a random package to my pubspec.yaml (I still hadn't added any), say [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), ran again `flutter pub get` and this time both Podfile and Podfile.lock were created. Weird behavior, but that's the way I worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this issue in 2022

then simply first of all backup the entire runner folder from your iOS directory
and then delete your entire iOS directory and then run ' flutter create . '
this command will recreate your project for all the platform after running this project go to the newly created iOS folder and then delete the runner folder and paste the runner folder you backed up before enjoy your issue will be. solved now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error and solved it with these two simple steps:

1. Delete only the `Podfile.lock` file
2. Run `flutter clean && flutter run`